# Express Typescript does not use Middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, middleware

I built a simple Auth Middleware but somehow the middleware does not get called at all, if I for instance throw an Error inside my middle function it just gets ignored nothing get printed.

I only need to call the auth middleware on the route below, just for test purposes.

My UserRoutes.ts

```
import auth from '../middleware/auth';

export default class UserRoutes {

  public UserController: UserController = new UserController();

  public routes(app: Application): void {
    // ...
    app.route('/api/users/me')
      .get(this.UserController.me, auth); // this is where I call my auth middleware
}
```

In my middleware I basically trim the Bearer Space and try to find the correct user from the token which I get after I log in. The tokens are saved correctly to my mongodb.

My auth middleware looks like this:

```
const auth = async (req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '');
  const msg = { auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' };

  if (!token) res.status(500).send(msg);

  try {
    const data: any = jwt.verify(token, JWT_KEY);
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: data._id, 'tokens.token': token });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("Could not find User");
    }

    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: 'Not authorized to access this resource.' });
  }
}

export default auth;
```

UserController.ts:

```
export class UserController {
   ///...
   public me(req: IUserRequest, res: Response) {
     res.send(req.user)
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.UserController.me`?  Please show that code as it gets executed before `auth` does so if it has problems or doesn't call `next()`, then `auth` will never get called.

Comment: @jfriend00 it refers to the UsersController in which the me method gets called

Comment: @jfriend00 updated the question with the me test method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `me` method is the first handler called and sends a response and ends all processing.  No further routes will be called.  For a middleware to actually behave as a middleware and do something, but then let other routes continue to be called, it needs to:

1. Not send a response.  Technically it could, but then there would be no point to the subsequent routes since you can only send done response per request.
2. Call `next()` which is the third argument passed to it (which you haven't declared) when it is done with its processing and it wishes for routing to continue.

So, because `me()` is first and it ends all routing, your `auth()` handler is never called.  Perhaps you meant to put the `auth()` handler first?  Routes are executed in the order they are registered in the code (assuming they match the current incoming URL).

Comment: But shouldn't the middleware before the actual method to check if the given user is authorized or not?

Comment: @utdev - Route handlers are called in the order declared (assuming they match the incoming URL).  So, `me()` will be called before `auth()`.  If you want `auth()` called first, then reverse the order.

Comment: Ah the order is important you say, so I do this `.get(auth, this.UserController.me);`

Comment: Yes changing the order worked, I thought the second param was specified for the middleware :D Thanks a lot, you may add the order in your answer :)

Comment: @utdev - Yes, that's right.  Also, keep in mind that there's really not much of a technical difference between what we call middleware and what we call a route handler.  They both have the same capabilities.  They are all just handlers that are called when the request arrives.  We call things middleware that don't usually send a response, but do some preparatory work before the code that would typically send the response, but they are not technically different.